# Https requests from Racket net/url

Tags: https, racket

I'm trying to pull data from a URL in Racket using

```
(html->xexp  (get-pure-port (string->url url)))
```

However, when url is an https, I get an error along the lines of

```
ssl-connect: connect failed (error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error)
```

What else do I need to be doing to handle https?

Comment: I can’t reproduce this. Running `(port->string (get-pure-port (string->url "https://www.google.com/")))` works just fine for me.

Comment: Actually it's looking like it may be a Ubuntu openssl problem : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1475228

Comment: It's also affecting my ability to install packages using raco pkg install ... Do you know if there's another way to install packages? Perhaps one that doesn't require openssl?

Comment: I’m afraid I do not, but it might be helpful to ask the mailing list—you’ll probably get better results there for that sort of question than asking here.